# Select a radio button programmatically based on its id or label

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How could I select a radio button programmatically based on its id or label?

```
<mx:FormItem label="Aménagé : " direction="horizontal" paddingLeft="13">                                            

  <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="ln_amenage" enabled="true" />

  <mx:RadioButton id="Oui" label="oui" groupName="ln_amenage" value="oui"/>

  <mx:RadioButton id="Non" label="non" groupName="ln_amenage" value="non"/>

  <mx:RadioButton id="Encours" label="encours" groupName="ln_amenage" value="encours"/>                                 

</mx:FormItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

In mxml markup

```
<mx:FormItem id="formItem" label="Aménagé : " direction="horizontal" paddingLeft="13">  
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="ln_amenage" enabled="true" />  
    <mx:RadioButton id="Oui" label="oui" groupName="ln_amenage" value="oui"/>   
    <mx:RadioButton id="Non" label="non" groupName="ln_amenage" value="non"/>   
    <mx:RadioButton id="Encours" label="encours" groupName="ln_amenage" value="encours"/>   
</mx:FormItem>
```

Note here `id` given for FormItem components.

```
private function selectRadioButtonByIdOrLabel(idOrLabel:String):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0,len:int = formItem.numChildren; i < len; i++) 
    {
        var item:UIComponent = formItem.getChildAt(i) as UIComponent;

        if(item && item is RadioButton && RadioButton(item).id == idOrLabel || RadioButton(item).label == idOrLabel)
        {
            RadioButton(item).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
        }
    }
}
```

Call method like

```
selectRadioButtonByIdOrLabel("non");
```

Comment: Welcome if above answer is helpful please accept as answer with upvote.